# Creating Controllers while using the Designer in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, designer

I'm creating a Database Application using the Designer in Visual Studio. I want to separate the Controller from the auto-generated code of the Designer but don't know the best way to do it.

Right now I'm adding partials to the Form class and implementing each controller in a different partial.

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this. Hopefully one where I can separate the controllers into their own classes.